# How to add data/model to a web app that users cannot add or edit themselves

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to be able to add and delete charities on a charities/index page but I don't want users to be able to do the same.

I need to create models/db from the charities since users will be selecting which one to donate to.

I am thinking there are probably going to be two ways to do this. 
1) Add any charity to the database from my console
2) Use an Admin gem/plug-in where I can get a dashboard and add charities there.

Are there any other ways? I'm fairly new to rails and a bit unsure how to go about executing this.

Comment: Hi - another more complex solution involves adding security and/or logons.  To get an idea of what this invloves visit Railscasts - http://railscasts.com/ - search episodes with cancan (has been replaced with the gem cancancan.  I can post relevent bits of my code is there solution appeals - Pierre

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For you the simplest would be to use [activeadmin](http://activeadmin.info/)

Then your User model will need [rolify](https://github.com/EppO/rolify):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  rolify
```

you can set somebody as admin with this code:

```
user.add_role :admin
```